# html img anti-aliasing

Tags: html, image

When using a small png image as src on an `<img>` tag some detail gets lost bzw. anti-aliasied.

As an example inspect this [image]
image and zoom in. After downloading it and opening it with photoshop for example it appears as expected.

I want to use this as an logo (thus a bit bigger that 16x16px) without it getting blurry. Is there a tag I can set to disable this kind of anti-aliasing?

Comment: html doesn't do any kind of compression, what are you talking about? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Inspect the element in an new tab zoom in, then download it and open it in photoshop or gimp (and zoom in) . Why are the two different in quality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the following for webkit and moz support

```
image-rendering: pixelated;
image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
```

resource: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/